# Why won't the Baskerville font display on an iPhone 3G running OS 3?

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts, ipod-touch, ios

I'm testing our app on a few different platforms, and for some reason the Baskerville font doesn't seem to show on an iPhone 3G running OS 3.1.3. Does anyone know why this might be? The systems I've tested which work okay are:

- Simulator
- iPhone 3GS, iOS 4.0
- iPad, iOS 3.2.1
- iPod touch 3rd Gen, iOS 4.0.2

Stumped here!

Thanks... Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Baskerville Family of fonts was not added until iOS 3.2 and iOS 4.0 inherited the APIs and additions to 3.2, which explains the results in your testing.

Comment: Thanks... That's a bit annoying unfortunately! Is there any way of embedding the font in my app?

Comment: The APIs to allow for embedding fonts also came in iOS 3.2 & 4.0  So, I do not think there is a clean way for 3.0.X.  I wish I had a better answer for you.